# Understanding what will happen in case i will encounter one of this exceptions in a project

Tags: java, exception

Hello I have to work at a project which I forked from github and I have some problems in understanding exactly what will happen when i will encounter of of the exceptions present in my code.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    databaseLink=DriverManager.getConnection(url,databaseuser,databasepassword);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: Could not find the JDBC driver");
    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    System.exit(0);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: Could not establish a connection to the database");
    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I have never used Logger class before and in order to understand what will happen. In case on of this exceptions will be caught the message will be somehow redirected and the message printed will be the one from system.out and it will end with exit code 0? If this is the case where exactly Logger will redirect the message, because i didn't manage to understand even after looking on the java documentation from the Logger class

Comment: it just LOGS things. adds it in a log, so you can look up the reason for the crash later on

Comment: Where exactly it'll end up depends on the configuration of the logger. How exactly that is configured again depends on which logger is actually used (check the import for `Logger`). And generally speaking you don't want to mix `System.out.println` with usage of a logger: when starting to use a logger, it's best practice to do all information/logging-style output via that logger or you can end up with an incomplete mess (i.e. some messages in a log file, others only printed to stdout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logger only write traces in file

Whit getLogger(this.getClass().getName())
They try identify where must write log trace, in this case where class name is configured (your project provably has properties configuration file or something like)

There indicates log tipe, text and, in this case, exception traze
Level.SEVERE, null, e)

SEVERE (highest value)
WARNING
INFO
CONFIG
FINE
FINER
FINEST

SEVERE is a big error, I can't continue with the execution, Stop application (Logger can't stop, it just says it will stop now). For example I can load the DDBB to continue with the execution.

null is the string that you locate in log file to search the traze, null is bad idea. Is normal put something like "Error: Could not find the JDBC driver" and delete line with System.out.prinln.

And 'e' is the error, the log write error line and all class afected.

Logger only write. This line Stop the execution.

```
System.exit(0);
```